# How to pause HTML5 audio tag when click on another audio tag in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to pause the playing audio if another one is played. I have this

```
            <ul class="music-list">

                <li *ngFor="let song of Songs">
                    <div class="music-panel">
                        <div class="music-image">
                            <img src="{{ song.song_image }}" alt="music-img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="music-detail">
                            <span class="date-remind">Season 1 / 10 September 2018</span>
                            <h4>{{ song.song_title | titlecase }}</h4>
                            <div class="music-play">
                                <audio controls>
                                    <source src="{{ song.audio_file }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                                </audio>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get a reference of all element in the view then loop throw them an run pause method

```
@ViewChildren('audio') audioElms :ElementRef[];
```

now on the template bind a method on the audio play event

```
<audio controls #audio (play)="paly(audio)">
     <source src="{{ song.audio_file }}" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

the play method will loop throw the audio elment and pause

```
onPaly(elm:HTMLAudioElement) {
  this.audioElms.forEach(({nativeElement:e})=>{
   if (e !== elm) {
     e.pause();
   }
  })
}
```

check the complete demo  [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xswwfh)

**Updated for better performance**

in case we have many elementd keep loop through theme everytime for just pause one of is a low preformance way.

simply we will save a reference of the current played audio element and stop when we play another one

```
  private currentPlayedElem: HTMLAudioElement = null;

  onPaly(elm: HTMLAudioElement) {
    if (this.currentPlayedElem && this.currentPlayedElem !== elm ) {
      this.currentPlayedElem.pause();
    }

    this.currentPlayedElem = elm;
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjdymi)

Comment: If you have 100+ audio files in a view, why would you loop through all of them if you only need to pause one and play another one?

Comment: @FrisoHoekstra thanks for mention this problem I have update my answer will very simple way

Answer (score 1):

You could omit the `<audio>` element from your template and move the player logic to a service:

```
export class AudioPlayerService {    
    private globalPlayer: HTMLMediaElement = new Audio();    
}
```

**UPDATE** Demo: https://angular-eg8uik.stackblitz.io/

You can keep track of the player's state using `addEventListener()`. Pass it to an Observable stream and use it in your component.

```
private playerState = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ isPlaying: false });

constructor() {
    this.globalPlayer.addEventListener('play', () => {
        this.playerState.next({ isPlaying: true, audioId: 'foo' });
    });

    this.globalPlayer.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        this.playerState.next({ isPlaying: false });
    });
}

getState(): Observable<any> {
    return this.playerState.asObservable();
}
```

Pass `getState()` to your custom audio player component and update the buttons accordingly.

You can also add functions for loading, playing, pausing, stopping, seeking, `currentTime` values, etc.

This will scale well because you have only one `MediaElement` and two `EventListeners` no matter how many files you have in your view. You are also more flexible with your UI, the native `<audio>` element is pretty limited as far as design goes.

Comment: I like your way and already voted , but can you provide a demo , you can fork one of my answer , this will be very helpful for others 

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to the play event in the capturing phase and pause all audio file except the target one:

```
    document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
        var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
        for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
            if(audios[i] != e.target){
                audios[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }, true);
```